# How to handle progress bar state when updates come from backgroud thread

Tags: android

It's a simple scenario:

1. You start some background, let's say, network operation in a separate thread.
2. Set your `ProgressBar` visible.
3. Go away from your app before network operation completed.
4. While your app is in background the network operation completes but you never receive a callback (or fired event) because you should unsubscribe your callbacks/event subscriptions to prevent undesired exceptions (you can only modify UI views from a main thread).
5. You resume the app and see `ProgressBar` on the screen despite your background operation has already been finished.

I'm curious what is the best way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Is the ProgressBar in your XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible option could be also using an event bus (for example https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and holding a sticky event when the network operation is completed and checking this in onResume of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a `Service` or an `IntentService`. While your app is in background I assume you hide the progress bar. When the app is in foreground You can bind to the Service's instance, having maybe a method that returns the current progress. If the progress is grater or equal to the max you show the progress again, otherwise you undertake another action

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern for those this type of scenario (can also include data processing, view updates, etc, etc) is:

```
/*
  `controller` is the object with reference to the task
  currently being executed.
  It can be anything:
      a network operation, 
      a file copy, 
      an image processing, 
      an asset loading, etc, etc...
*/

public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   myView.setSomeProperty(controller.getCurrentValue());
   controller.subscribe(this);
}

public void onStop() {
   controller.unsubscribe(this);
   super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onControllerSubscriptionUpdate(int newValue){
   myView.setSomeProperty(newValue);
}
```

that way, every time the Activity or Fragment is coming to the foreground, your view gets updated with the latest parameter.